# how to install git_extension on mac

Tags: git, macos, mono, git-extensions

I want to install git extension base on this instruction

http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

but after I run this mono `GitExtensions.exe` comment I face this problem:
mono quit unexpectedly

[image: picture of my error]

Comment: If Git Extensions still crashes because it is unable to load a plugin, empty the plugins folder.

Comment: i dont install any plugin yet! how can i do that?

Comment: That documentation now targets Windows only. For Mac, use an alternative Git client (there is a lot).

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find the answer and I used 'sourceTree' instead of 'gitExtension' for mac